# AdMob Native ads inside listview is permitted?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, admob

Looking at admob docs, I can see that there are examples of good and bad implementations of banner and interstitial but nothing about native ads.

I am thinking of adding native ads in my listview but I have a few concerns:

1. is adding native ads as items in a listview against admob policies?
2. if permitted, how many items need to be between ads? Does the ad need to be the same in the list, or add new ad each time the item gets visible?

Comment: Thinking about same question and the wired thing is google created a complete new type of ads wihout any proper documention about where,why to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Nope. Native ads were designed to work in apps with scrolling lists of content. They're a great way to go.
2. There's no policy about how many items should be between ads, but there *is* a rule that no more than one ad should ever be onscreen at once. So you should have at least enough space between ads to make sure that doesn't happen. It's also a good idea to avoid cramming a bunch of ads close together because it can aggravate your users, of course.

You might be interested in the [RecyclerView example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/advanced/NativeExpressRecyclerViewExample) for Native Ads Express we just put up on GitHub. An iOS example using UITableView is in the works as well, and will be posted to our [iOS repo](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples) when it's done.

Comment: Well, it's quite a nice surprise of seeing who answered my question after seeing the Firebase native ads video :) Thank you for answering my concerns, I'll start implementing native ads to see how it goes.

Comment: another short question, are there any limitations in terms of ad background, I mean if my list has items similar to a CardView, with white background, can the ad have a white background and same CardView layout as the items, or it is too close looking to an item? I guess my question is, do I need to differentiate the ad item background from the rest of the items in the list?

Comment: I don't know of any background color requirements. Each ad the SDK gives you will have a little thing in the corner called an "attribution icon" that identifies it as an ad, so users will know what's up. :)

Comment: Since you are so helpful, maybe you can answer me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576529/admob-native-ads-express-not-receiving-test-ads   I am not able to make the app show Test Native Ads  Express. I've added the ad id as on GitHub but that also looks like real ads to me.

Comment: Also, after implementating Native Ads Express it seems that I am getting a lot of `Failed to load ad: 3` which most likely is because of no ads in inventory to send. This makes me wonder if this happens in real app, how much money I'll be making... In case of a failing ad to load, can I put my own layout instead of the app? Let's say a layout similar to the add, pointing to another one of my apps?

Comment: I've had my app rejected multiple times now as they say more than one ad is on the page despite them not being able to show me one screen with 2 ads, they seem to believe a list view is a page

Answer (score 0):

1.There is nothing like that

2.You can have any number of ads between your content .There is nothing to restrict that .But thing is if you put more number of ads the user will get irritated to use your app.So maintain some standard number of ads like 1 ads for 5 contents. You have to place new ad in each 5th position because you will not get revenue if you place same ad twice .There is some called impression which is getting fired on each ad display which fire only once for one native ad object .