# AdMob Native Ads Express not receiving test ads

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I am familiar with AdMob and with banner and interstials.
I'm adding native ads functionality and something weird is happening because even if using the same AdRequest as for insterstitials/banners, for banners/interstitials I am getting test ads but for native ads, I get the live ones.

```
 adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("mydeviceIdFromLogcat").build();
```

So my question is, native ads do not have test ads?

Comment: it does shows test ads. Are you getting any error in your logs? see this example https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/BannerExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/bannerexample/MyActivity.java

Comment: As I mentioned, the test ads work for banners and interstitials but not for native ads express.

Comment: any error in logs?

Comment: No errors from what I see... ads load just as no .addTestDevice has been set.

Comment: I have exactly the same behaviour as you: I also used to banner & interstitials but no way to obtain test ads for native ads, only real ones. And no error/warning in the logs.

Comment: For information there is a post in the Google Mobile Ads SDK Developers group discussing the problem [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/XsWEj7qa5NI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Native ads do not provide test ads the way we are used to (via `addTestDevice()` on `AdRequest`).

From the [Google Mobile Ads SDK Developers group conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/XsWEj7qa5NI) on this subject:

> Veer Arjun Busani(Mobile Ads SDK Team) - For now, you would not be able to load test ads for Native Ad Express and I do not have any ETA on when this might change.

Note that depending on your country and ISP, you may use test Ad Unit ID ([Native Ads Avanced documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-advanced#test_your_code)). Personally I never make them work (`Received error HTTP response code: 403` logs.